# Javascript regex find a string like htttp://domain.com/file.zip

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which is basically a body of a page, and I would like to find all links that contains .zip, but I need the whole link.

Comment: That's certainly possible. Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this you mean?

```
https?:\/\/.+?\.zip
```

This will match anything that starts with `http://` or `https://` and ends with `.zip`.

Comment: Thank you @GMchris for trying to help me, based on your response I could make it work.
That was my final solution.
`/http.+?\.(zip|pdf)/gmi`

ps: really can't understand why people vote negative when you tried to help. We need more community on this community.